# Why I can't select a table existing in my database?

Tags: php, mysqli

**EDIT**

I connected to my database and I want to verify if I can select my table. They do exist but I always get "Unable to select (one of) the Databases"

```php
if ($DBConnect === false) { //We verify if we are connected to the Database
    echo "<p> Connection failed </p>\n";
} else {
    //We want to check if there is the two table in the database
    $sqlPat = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_patient`";
    $sqlUser = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_user`";
    $ResultPat = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sqlPat);
    $ResultUser = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sqlUser);

    if (empty($ResultPat) || empty($ResultUser)) {
        echo "<p> Unable to select (one of) the Databases</p>";
    } else {
        $sqlTruncP = "TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl_patient`";
        $sqlTruncU = "TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl_user`";
        $QResultTP = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sqlTruncP);
        $QResultTU = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sqlTruncU);
        if ($QResultTP) {
            echo "<p>  Well done my mate ".$sqlTruncP. " done ". $DBConnect->info."</p>";
            if ($QResultTU) {
                echo "<p>  Well done my mate ".$sqlTruncU. " done ". $DBConnect->info."</p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p> No Way Hose - Unable to perform SQL Truncate Table </p>";
        }
    }
```

I get 'No Way Hose - Unable to perform SQL Truncate Table' each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ResultPat and $ResultUser will return an array not string therefore you have to check with the method given below the array is empty or not.

```
if (empty($ResultPat) || empty($ResultUser)){
echo "<p> Unable to select (one of) the Databases</p>";
}
```

you can also check the values in the array but just using

```
echo "<pre>"print_r($ResultUser);die;
```

the above code will print your array elements and die will stop the code after your array will be printed on the screen.

**Second Question Answer: -**

```
if ($QResultTP)
{   echo " Well done my mate ";
    echo "  Well done my mate ";

}else
{
    echo "<p> No Way Hose - Unable to perform SQL Truncate Table </p>";
}
```

**explaination: -**

In your 1st question query will return you an array it may be empty or can have data. empty used to check null,'',0, values in the variable.

they truncate query will not return you any data. it will just truncate the tables.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I want to truncate them and I have the same problem, I tried to use your method but it still print me (I put my code on an edit in my question)

Comment: I added it in my question, do you need more of my code ?

Comment: I changed my code according to your second answer but I still get `No Way Hose - Unable to perform SQL Truncate Table`, even if I have a table that I should be able to truncate. Do you have an idea why I have this result ?

Comment: please show me the code how you did it because it is working in my case.  I am gettign Well done my mate.


if (($QResultTP) || ($QResultTU)){
"  Well done my mate ";
}else {
echo "truncate failed";
}

Comment: My problem was only coming from the fact that I have foreign keys in one of the table I wanted to truncate, I just needed to add a delete in cascade in the properties of my table